# Bootstrap 4: Image is being rotated and I can't seem to rotate the image without overwritting the css properties

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, rotation, transform

I am making a web page using bootstrap 4 and the image I have chosen rotates to the right and is not rendering properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI1Dg.png)

The problem I see is making the image rotate without over writing other css properties.

In this case: img class:"img-fluid"

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
    <!--  STYLE  SECTION

      <style type="text/css">

      img {      transform: rotate(270deg);        }

    </style>
  -->
                <img class="img-fluid" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="C:\Additional Folders\Harvard CS50\Project 0\project0\layoutit\src\larger pic.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
```

As you may have noticed above, I successfully rotated the image with style tag in the html code but this made the image cross over into other divs and won't work.

The other issue is that boot strap 4 has many css pages and I am not sure if I am making changes that will not be over written later.

For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNbxt.png)

I am starting to think that my image is rendering that way because its a rectangular image and the width is not wide enough by the image properties, or it might render wide instead.

Does anyone have experience in this matter?
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

when you rotate the image, if you don't want it to pass to the other divs, you can hide the overhanging parts of the image. Like this:

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 img-container" style="overflow: hidden; height: "to fit on the screen"; width: "to fit on the screen">
```

CSS:

```
.img-container{
  height: "you have to arrange it yourself";
  width: "you have to arrange it yourself";
  overflow: "hidden";
};
```

when you do that, probably part of the image won't be visible. You can play with the size of the picture and fit it on the screen. Also, if you don't want to work with css to rotate the image, there are programs that edit the image before you upload it. Like : http://convert-my-image.com/ImageConverter;

if you don't want to change the properties of the bootstrap itself, I suggest you assign your own private names for the classes you use. Thus bootstrap is not affected by the changes you make.

Comment: Hey that totally worked. I am wondering why when I try that same code in my own css style sheet it doesn't work.

In my style sheet I tried:

.col-lg-4 {overflow: hidden; height: "to fit on the screen"" width: "to fit on the screen"}

It only seems to work inline from the div as you sent it to me. 
Thanks So Much!! I just want to understand why the bootstrap is not being overwritten in my own css file. 

Also, the quotation after "overflow doesn't end until after screen"" 
that has be a little baffled.

Comment: I'm glad it works. you have to crush the Bootstrap with css. bootstrap is dominant because you define it directly in your html page. the code you write on your css page you can add  " !important" , but this is not usually recommended. In general, a class is defined in bootstrap so that you can access the solutions you want. I suggest you examine the Bootstrap documentation in more detail. I have too many quotes. I'm editing my answer. If there was a solution, you can mark my answer as resolved.